# The same + singular or plural noun?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

I know that we can say: You have the same book as me/I do.

---

How about:

1. You and I have the same books.
2. You and I have the same book.

---

**What are the differences between them?**

`Thank you`

Comment: The first means there are several books, which you both have. The second is about one single book, and you both have a copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. means you have the same **books** as me/I do.
2. means you have the same **book** as me/I do.

Additionally, you can say:

- Your **books** are the same as mine/my **books**.

OR

- Your **book** is the same as mine/my **book**.

***AND***

- Your **books** and mine/my **books** are the same

OR

- Your **book** and mine/my **book** are the same